SDL-GPU Rendering to texture results in rough edges
I have a texture and I render a circle to it using SDL-GPU, then I render this texture to the window:
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_gpu.h"

int main() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
        return 1;

    GPU_Target* window = GPU_Init(800, 600, GPU_DEFAULT_INIT_FLAGS);

    GPU_Image* texture = GPU_CreateImage(800, 600, GPU_FORMAT_RGBA);
    GPU_SetImageFilter(texture, GPU_FILTER_LINEAR);
    
    GPU_Target* texture_target = GPU_LoadTarget(texture);

    GPU_Clear(texture_target);
    GPU_CircleFilled(texture_target, 200, 300, 100, { 255, 0, 0, 255 });
    GPU_Flip(texture_target);

    bool running = true;

    SDL_Event event;
    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        GPU_Clear(window);

        GPU_Blit(texture, nullptr, window, 400, 300);;
        GPU_CircleFilled(window, 600, 300, 100, { 255, 0, 0, 255 });

        GPU_Flip(window);
    }

    GPU_FreeImage(texture);
    GPU_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

However, the rendered texture appears rough, especially on the edges of the circle (left), compared to a circle rendered directly to the window (right):

The difference is subtle but noticeable.
What might be causing this issue?
Here's what I've tried so far:
Texture filtering is set to GPU_FILTER_LINEAR so I don't think that's the issue.
I tried enabling multisampling with the following code (before initializing SDL):
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1); 
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 4);

But it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Looks like a (lack of) anti-aliasing issue.
